# Can we use JMX in VM configuration like Heap size?

Tags: java, jmx

I am new to JMX .I am going through JMX and found that we can use JMX agent to  manage/monitor  my application , but here I have a question . Can we use JMX for JVM configuration like increase in heap size etc.

Any body has idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum heap size is allocated when the JVM starts up. It cannot be changed while running (as it has to be reserved in advance)

You can use JMX to configure other parameters. A common choice is to change logging levels for example.